# Как делать запросы в базу данных из файла хуков?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, codeigniter

Написал хук для редиректов на сайте, но как сделать так, чтобы он подгрузил модель ну или просто писать там запросы в бд?

На просьбу: `$this->CI->load->model('Urlpostreplacer_model');` говорит:

`Unable to locate the model you have specified: Urlpostreplacer_model`

файл модели:

```
if ( !defined('BASEPATH') )
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Urlrostreplacer_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getURLs() {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM url_post_replacer');
        $result = $query->result_array();  
        return $result;
    }

}
```

хук

```
$hook['post_system'] = array(
    'class' => 'CustomUrlPostReplacer',
    'function' => 'index',
    'filename' => 'CustomUrlPostReplacer.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => ''
);
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы запутались с регистром букв, в `CI`  это важно.

У Вас:

`$this->CI->load->model('Urlpostreplacer_model');`

А должно быть так:

`$this->CI->load->model('urlpostreplacer_model');`

Далее перепроверьте модель:

`\application\models\Urlpostreplacer_model.php`

И в ней: `class Urlpostreplacer_model extends CI_Model`

Comment: Вообще ничего не показывает, 500 возвращает

Comment: @russell 500 - это уже скорей ошибка в скриптах, перепроверяйте

Comment: Все сделал как вы написали, как только раскомменчиваю строку:
`$this->CI->load->model('urlpostreplacer_model');`
возвращает 500

Comment: Заметил, что когда меняю точку привязки хука с `post_controller` на  `post_system` то все ок

Answer (score 0):

Обошелся без привлечения к содействию моделей,
написал напрямую в файле класса хука, работает:

```
$this->CI->load->database();
$query = $this->CI->db->query('SELECT * FROM url_post_replacer');
$result = $query->result_array();
```